# Images taking too long to load on Shopify

Tags: javascript, image, shopify, liquid

I am trying to optimize a Shopify website and I noticed that the images are being loaded via this script

```
{% assign featured_image = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}
<div class="flexslider product_gallery {% if product-images == blank %}product_slider{% endif %}" id="product-{{ product.id }}-gallery">
  <ul class="slides">
    {% for image in product.images %}
    <li data-thumb="{{ image | product_img_url: 'small' }}" data-title="{% if image.alt contains 'youtube' or image.alt contains 'vimeo' %}{{ product.title }}{% else %}{{ image.alt | escape }}{% endif %}">
      {% if image.alt contains 'youtube' or image.alt contains 'vimeo' %}
      {% assign src = image.alt | split: 'src="' %}
      {% assign src = src[1] | split: '"' | first %}
      {% if src contains '?' %}
      {% assign src = src | append: '&amp;autoplay=1' %}
      {% else %}
      {% assign src = src | append: '?autoplay=1' %}
      {% endif %}
      <div class="video-container {% if image.alt contains 'vimeo' %}vimeo{% else %}youtube{% endif %}">
        <div>
          <a href="{{ src }}" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" data-fancybox-group="{{ product.id }}" title="{{ product.title | escape }}">
            {{ image.alt }}
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% else %}
      <a href="{{ image | product_img_url: 'master' }}" class="fancybox" rel="group" data-fancybox-group="{{ product.id }}" title="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
        <img width="64" height="64" src="{{ 'loader.gif' | asset_url }}" data-src="{{ image | product_img_url: 'large' }}" data-src-retina="{{ image | product_img_url: '1024x1024' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}" data-index="{{ forloop.index0 }}" data-image-id="{{ image.id }}" data-cloudzoom="zoomImage: '{{ image | product_img_url: 'master' }}', tintColor: '{{ settings.shop_bg_color }}', zoomPosition: 'inside', zoomOffsetX: 0, touchStartDelay: 250" class="cloudzoom {% if featured_image.id == image.id %}featured_image{% endif %}" />
      </a>
      {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now everything seems fine here but when I check the loading time of images on product page each image shows about 2 to 2.5 seconds of loading time even though the images are about 30kb in size, see image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCvcr.png)

Anyone had any idea why this is happening and how I can troubleshoot this? Seems that the page is using something called 'flexslider' and after Googling for a while I couldn't find what the problem is.

[Website](https://wearsaga.com/products/3d)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe it's your connection. I'm seeing 224ms and the like. 
What page are you on?

Comment: @bknights I am on this page https://wearsaga.com/products/3d and I check it via chrome dev tools ,the images take 2.3s each to load which is very weird.

Comment: same deal. Those images are coming from Shopify's CDN. I'm getting all of them at under 300ms each. Try pinging cdn.shopify.com and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

As your theme is calling the master image size in parameter loading time may be a bit long if your product image is very large/heavy.

You may limit size loaded by using size parameters as explained here: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/url-filters#size-parameters